# Unique constraint with FluentMigrator

Tags: c#, postgresql, fluent-migrator

How can I add "lower(title)" in creation of my table with FluentMigrator, I want to have case insensetive unique constraint in postgre

Answer (score 1):

Insofar as I know you cannot solve this in the table definition as the `UNIQUE` constraint will only accept a column name. You could create an index on the title column with a UNIQUE clause, which effectively does what you want:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX title_unique ON table_name (lower(title));
```

This of course also gives you an explicit index on title, which is required to enforce the constraint anyway.

Comment: This works on postgres, but doesn't work on MS SQL, I need solution for both databases. Now I'm using IfDatabase(). Do you know better solution?

Comment: You were asking in the PostgreSQL forum. Perhaps ask for a similar solution on the MS SQL tag